# Install CGAL lib version 4.5.1

Tags: 14.04, software-installation

How do I specifically install CGAL lib 4.5.1 ?

Does sudo apt-get install libcgal-dev help?

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.I previously had CGAL 4.6.1 (which I removed) but I need CGAL 4.5.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use version 4.5.1 in Trusty you have to compile it yourself

- Install some development libraries

  ```
  sudo apt-get install libgmp-dev
  sudo apt-get install libmpfr-dev
  ```
- Install a helper tool to create and install a deb package later

  ```
  sudo apt-get install checkinstall
  ```
- Download and extract the source code

  ```
  mkdir -p ~/src
  cd ~/src
  wget https://gforge.inria.fr/frs/download.php/file/34400/CGAL-4.5.1.tar.gz
  tar xf CGAL-4.5.1.tar.gz
  ```
- Build via

  ```
  cd CGAL-4.5.1
  cmake .
  make
  ```
- Install

  ```
  sudo checkinstall
  ```

Comment: Can you tell me where is src folder created?

Comment: In your home folder. `~` is a abbreviation for your home folder.

Comment: Which path should I give to run any program using CGAL? Earlier (when i had 4.6.2) it was being installed in usr/lib/CGAL directory.

Comment: In `/usr/local/lib` You can list the installed files via `dpkg -L cgal`

Comment: No, there is no CGAL folder in /usr/local/lib.

Comment: Have you checked the output of `dpkg -L cgal`?

Comment: yes. it says:
pkg-query: package 'cgal' is not installed
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.

Comment: Have you used all steps  exactly as described  in my answer

Comment: yes. except installing check install.

Comment: Use it. Without the command, nothing will be installed

Comment: ok i navigated to main directory and installed checkinstall and again navigated to CGAL directory to run the last command.  what should I do next?

Comment: Can you see the list of installed files?

Comment: The sudo checkinstall is still working . I will let you know.. Thanks a lot for the help BTW.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. Everything is working. The CGAL examples are running . just the path has changed to usr/local/lib/CGAL